# How to control the SerialPort when program is force terminated?

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I am making a `WinForm` program that uses the `SerialPort` to control the amount of light. 100% for the first 10 minutes, 97% for the next 20 minutes, and 94% for the remaining 30 minutes.

The problem occur when I force close the program. I don't have a way to turn off the lights currenly working.

Is there any way to solve this?

---

**Edit**

Is it possible to create an event that occurs just before the program exits?

Comment: Can't you run the program again and turn it off?

Comment: @shingo You can do that, but the stability of the program is poor.

Comment: Your Form should habe a `Closing` event. Please check if this is fired when you force close your application

Comment: @MongZhu I solved it thank :D I wrote a post about what I solved according to the method you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Based on @Mong Zhu**'s answer, I solved it like this:

```cs
FormClosing += (sender, e) =>
{
  if (serialPort.IsOpen)
  {
      serialPort.WriteBytes(Percent0); // turning off the light
      serialPort.Close();
  }
};
```

If you add a `Form.Closing` event, it will work not only when the form closes, but also when the process exits.